# How to take backup of all the data of all the apps from canvas 4 mobile

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, backup, windows

I have some apps that contains information like Account summery, TODO list, Notes, Password saver etc. Recently I have lost my cellphone so I lost all my app data as well. I don't want to loose my app data. So is there any way what I can take all my app data backup into my PC or SD card and restore back when required. TIA

```
FYI 
PC-OS : windows 7
Mobile OS : Android 4.2.2
Mobile model : CANVAS 4 (a210)
Hardware manufacturer : MICROMAX
```

Comment: Have you checked out our [backup tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info)? The answer is already there. As your device runs Android 4.x, take a closer look at `adb backup` and *Helium Backup*, both solutions are mentioned there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root your phone and use *Titanum Backup* app.